# when xorring string read from file, results do not match the exact string hardcoded

Tags: c++, encryption

I am mostly a PHP programmer, dabbling in C++.

I have an XOR function (to do some simple obfuscation) that looks like this:

```
string* xor_string(string& text,const char* key){
        unsigned int i=0;
        unsigned int j=0;
        string* tmp= new string();

        // Iterate through each character
        for(i=0; i < text.length(); ){
            for(j=0; ( (j < strlen(key)) && (i < text.length() ) ); j++,i++){   
                *tmp += (text[i] ^ key[j]);
            }
        }

        return tmp;
    }
```

(That returned pointer is cleaned up).

I am calling that function like so:

```
string* tmp = xor_string( *mytext,cfg_crypt_key );
```

**cfg_crypt_key** a const char* , read from an xml file. The value is "mykey". I have outputted its value to a log file and its reading correctly. However when xoring the text, its not producing the correct results. When I hard code that exact string like:

```
cfg_crypt_key = "mykey";
```

The correct results are produced.

I thought it was some encoding problem but upon **strcmp(cfg_crypt_key,"mykey")==0** is evaluating TRUE

This has been bugging me for days. Any help would be appreciated.

NOTE: the text I am sending is crypttext that passed thru the same xor function. I am just trying to decrypt it now. Thats how I know its not the correct output because the resulting "clear" text does not match the input clear text.

**Edit**: The problem seems to have been solved by my usage of std::string exclusively instead of mixing char* and strings, I have no idea why

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org).

Comment: [OT]: returning `std::string` seems more natural than `std::string*`...

Comment: [OT]: You might cache `strlen(key)` result.

Comment: Jarod42, I get what u are saying, however these strings are actually 1000 line text files read into the string, I am trying to use the heap as much as possible to avoid any, stackoverflows

Comment: The problem seems to have been solved by my usage of std::string exclusively instead of mixing char* and strings, I have no idea why

Comment: Note that std::string stores its data on the heap even if the object itself is on the stack (at least, using the default allocator.  I suppose you could try making a stack allocator if you wanted.)